# ExternalInterface.call leaks in IE 9

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, memory-leaks, externalinterface

I created a really simple SWF to demonstrate:

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

    public class FlashIELeak extends MovieClip {

        public function FlashIELeak() {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);
        }

        private function onFrame(e:Event):void {
            ExternalInterface.call("test", null);
        }
    }
}
```

Load that in Chrome, no problems.  Memory stays more or less fixed.

Load that in IE and memory just keeps going up and up - about 30k/s.  You don't even need to declare a test function.  Just embed the swf in the page and you've got a leak.  In our project, we're passing an object with several properties and IE is leaking like 120k/s.  Not good.

Anyone seen this before?  I wasn't able to find any other posts related to this.

Comment: Nice! does it crashes in the end?

Comment: If you let it run long enough yup.  We had clients complain about IE crashing and we narrowed it down to this issue.

Comment: And if you don't use `ExternalInterface.call()` (in your enter frame handler), all is good in IE memory wise? You might also specify which version of IE, Flash, and the Windows OS you're seeing this problem in. Finally, I would try to dial things down a bit (enter frame events happen quite frequently). What happens if you use `ExternalInterface.call()` with a `Timer` that fired, say every 10 seconds. I'm guessing the problem just occurs more slowly...

Comment: Tried firing every 10 seconds instead using a setInterval and still get the leak.  It goes up about 6k every 10 seconds.

Comment: Actually, it isn't as consistent.  Sometimes it'll jump about 80k and then come back to what it was about a minute later.  Over time however it does seem to increase.  Harder to tell though because it's so slow.  I'll let it run a while and see what happens.

Comment: Tested on IE 9 with Flash 11.6 on Windows 7.

Comment: This seems to have been fixed in IE 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was post in famous russian blog about 2 years ago. Alexander Kozlovskij (aka Fizzer) explained this problem. Here is workaround he created:

```
package ru.kozlovskij.external
{
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    /**
     * @author a.kozlovskij
     * @copy flash.external.ExternalInterface
     */
    public final class ExternalInterfaceExtended
    {
        private static const instance :ExternalInterfaceExtended= new ExternalInterfaceExtended();
        private static var methodName :String;

        /**
         * U can't instanciate this class, because it implements a Singletone pattern.
         * @copy flash.external.ExternalInterface.ExternalInterface()
         */
        public function ExternalInterfaceExtended()
        {
            instance && new ExternalInterface();
            methodName = '__flash__addCallback_' + ExternalInterface.objectID;
        }

        private static function updateJS():void
        {
            const jsFunc :String = 'function(){ ' +
                methodName + ' = __flash__addCallback = function(flashObj, methodName)' +
                '{' +
                '    alert("JS: called overridden __flash__addCallback(" + arguments[0] + ", " + arguments[1] + ")");' +
                '    flashObj[methodName] = ' +
                '     (function(methodName)' +
                '     {' +
                '     return function()' +
                '     {' +
                '     this.CallFunction(\'\' + __flash__argumentsToXML(arguments,  + \'\');' +
                '     };' + //dangling semi-colon for IE 6
                '     })(methodName);' + //force re-closure to prevent IE memory leaks
                '};' +
                '}';

            ExternalInterface.call(jsFunc);
        }

        /**
         * Fixed: Mem leaks in native addCallback-js-closure.
         * @copy flash.external.ExternalInterface.addCallback()
         */
        public static function addCallback(functionName :String, closure :Function):void
        {
            updateJS();
            ExternalInterface.addCallback(functionName, closure);
            //ExternalInterface.call(methodName, functionName);
            //ExternalInterface.call('__flash__addCallback_ext', null, functionName);
        }

        /**
         * @copy flash.external.ExternalInterface.call()
         */
        public static function call(functionName :String, ...parameters :Array):*
        {
            parameters.unshift(functionName);
            return ExternalInterface.call.apply(ExternalInterfaceExtended, parameters);
        }

        /**
         * @copy flash.external.ExternalInterface.available
         */
        public static function get available():Boolean
        {
            return ExternalInterface.available;
        }

        /**
         * @copy flash.external.ExternalInterface.objectID
         */
        public static function get objectID():String
        {
            return ExternalInterface.objectID;
        }

        /**
         * @copy flash.external.ExternalInterface.marshallExceptions
         */
        public static function get marshallExceptions():Boolean
        {
            return ExternalInterface.marshallExceptions;
        }

        public static function set marshallExceptions(value :Boolean):void
        {
            ExternalInterface.marshallExceptions = value;
        }
    }
}
```

So, you just need to use ExternalInterfaceExtended class instead of regular ExternalInterface.

Comment: Ah wow.  Thanks for that.  We ended up using a different approach so I unfortunately can't test this.

Comment: Original article: https://web.archive.org/web/20130310234950/http://flash-ripper.com/articles/externalinterface-ie-memory-leaks-workaround